# Add data to table with SQL connection in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have a CRM table in a database that employees need to update. I have used a windows form and use an SQL connection to link them but I keep getting an error that the sytanx is incorrect near the key 'In' and I don't really understand why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'traficoDataSet.Inteserado_En' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.inteserado_EnTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Inteserado_En);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'traficoDataSet.Contacto' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.contactoTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Contacto);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'traficoDataSet.Tipo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tipoTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Tipo);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'agora_UsuariosDataSet.Usuarios' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                this.usuariosTableAdapter.Fill(this.agora_UsuariosDataSet.Usuarios);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'traficoDataSet.Como' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.comoTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Como);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'traficoDataSet.Trafico' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.traficoTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Trafico);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new     SqlConnection(global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.TraficoConnectionString);
            try
            {

                string sql = "INSERT INTO Trafico ('Nombre', 'Apedillo', 'Correo', 'Teléfono', 'Como', 'Comercial', 'Tipo', 'Contacto','Inteserado En') Values(" + nombreTextBox.Text + "," + apedilloTextBox.Text + "," + correoTextBox.Text + "," + teléfonoTextBox.Text + "," + comoComboBox.Text + "," + comercialComboBox.Text + "," + tipoComboBox.Text + "," + contactoComboBox.Text + ","+inteserado_EnComboBox.Text+"";
                SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                cn.Open();
                exeSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.traficoTableAdapter.Fill(this.traficoDataSet.Trafico);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should look into using [parameters or stored procs.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: I agree with this for many reasons,more than just SQL injection.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with that insert statement. Column names should not be wrapped in single quotes (of course a couple of those have to be wrapped in square brackets). You really should parameterize the values to avoid bobby tables (http://bobby-tables.com/). If you insist on the sql injection route you need to wrap the values in single quotes when they are string literals.

Comment: save yourself the headache and port that hard coded SQL over into using a Stored Procedure as well as learn how to construct Parameterized Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you need to wrap your values in single quotes for strings like so

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Trafico ('Nombre', 'Apedillo', 'Correo', 'Teléfono', 'Como', 'Comercial', 'Tipo', 'Contacto','Inteserado En') Values('" + nombreTextBox.Text + "','" + apedilloTextBox.Text + "','" + correoTextBox.Text + "','" + teléfonoTextBox.Text + "','" + comoComboBox.Text + "','" + comercialComboBox.Text + "''," + tipoComboBox.Text + "','" + contactoComboBox.Text + "','" + inteserado_EnComboBox.Text +"')";
```

Like mentioned above use parameters to avoid sql injection.  It also makes it easier to modify your query when adding multiple rows.  You can use the same query string and just swap the values.  You can use parameters like so

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Trafico ('Nombre', 'Apedillo', 'Correo', 'Teléfono', 'Como', 'Comercial', 'Tipo', 'Contacto','Inteserado En') Values(@Nobre, @Apedillo, @ Correo, @Telephono, @Como, @Comercial, @Tipo, @Contacto, @Inteserado_En)";


exeSql.Parameters.Add("@Nobre", SqlDataType.Varchar).Value = nombreTextBox.Text;
exeSql.Parameters.Add("@Apedillo", SqlDataType.Varchar).Value = apedilloTextBox.Text
//and so on
```

You no longer need to add single quotes around the variable because you define the datatype in the parameter.  The sqlcommand will know to treat it like a string since it is defined that way.  I also noticed the space in the column name "Inteserado En".  Make sure that is correct.  Generally you should not add spaces for column names. But it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the string sql to:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Trafico (Nombre, Apedillo, Correo, Teléfono, Como, Comercial, Tipo, Contacto,Inteserado En) Values('" + nombreTextBox.Text + "','" + apedilloTextBox.Text + "','" + correoTextBox.Text + "','" + teléfonoTextBox.Text + "','" + comoComboBox.Text + "','" + comercialComboBox.Text + "','" + tipoComboBox.Text + "','" + contactoComboBox.Text + "','" + inteserado_EnComboBox.Text + "')";
```

You forgot to put the closing bracket and also to put the " ' " character for the column values. You should also verify that all the columns are string. If there are some numbers you can omit the " ' " character between values.